# Directive to update a datepicker does not update model

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I am using the timepicker from https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker in an angularjs project.

The html looks like:

```
<div uxdatepicker ng-model="selectedDate"
  data-provide="datepicker-inline" ng-change="on_date_changed()">
</div>
```

I have created a directive like:

```
app.directive("uxdatepicker", function ()
{
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller)
        {
            element.datepicker({
                language: "no",
                format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
                datesDisabled : ["2017-10-10"],
                maxViewMode: "days"
            }).on("changeDate", function (e)
            {
                scope.$apply(function ()
                {
                    controller.$setViewValue(e.date);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

But $scope.selectedDate in my main controller will never be updated with the selected date.

Why not?

I have alerted e.date in the change date handler to make sure it holds the selected date.

Comment: I wish to delete this question, because the error was elsewhere. I had the uxdatepicker inside a ng-repeat and it seems like it could not modify $scope.selectedDate there. Instead I used e.selectedDate where e is the ng-repeat item.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote following directive to make it work:

```
app.directive('wmAiGridDatePicker', ['$timeout', '$parse', function ($timeout, $parse) {
        return {//this datePicker will show the date in the wanted format and save it (ng-model) with the default format of yy-mm-dd
            template: '<input type="text"  style="cursor: pointer;border-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);height: 22px;padding-left: 6px;margin-right: 13px;margin-top: 10px;">',
            replace: true,
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {},
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

                scope.time = {
                    hours: 0,
                    minutes: 0
                };

                var getModel = function () {
                    return controller.$modelValue;
                };

                var options = {
                    format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
                    , autoclose: 'true'                            
                    , todayBtn: "linked"
                    ,todayHighlight:true
                };

                element.datepicker(options);

                element.datepicker().on('hide', function () {

                    $timeout(function () {
                        var date_ = element.datepicker('getDate');

                        if (date_) {
                            date_.setHours(scope.time.hours);
                            date_.setMinutes(scope.time.minutes);                            
                            controller.$setViewValue(moment(date_).unix());
                        }


                        scope.$apply();
                    }, 1);
                });

                element.datepicker().on('changeDate', function () {

                    $timeout(function () {
                        var date_ = element.datepicker('getDate');

                        if (date_) {
                            date_.setHours(scope.time.hours);
                            date_.setMinutes(scope.time.minutes);
                            controller.$setViewValue(moment(date_).unix());
                        }


                        scope.$apply();
                    }, 1);
                });

                scope.onModelChange = function () {                   

                    var date = controller.$modelValue;

                    if (angular.isDate(date)) {
                        scope.time.hours = date.getHours();
                        scope.time.minutes = date.getMinutes();
                    }
                };

                controller.$render = function () {
                    var unixDate = controller.$modelValue;

                    if (!unixDate) {
                        return;
                    }

                    var date = new Date(unixDate * 1000);

                    if (angular.isDate(date)) {
                        scope.time.hours = date.getHours();
                        scope.time.minutes = date.getMinutes();
                    }

                    element.datepicker('setDate', date);
                    element.datepicker('update');
                };

                scope.$watch(getModel, function (newVal) {                    
                    scope.onModelChange();                 
                }, true);

                if (controller) {
                    controller.$render();
                }
            }
        };
    }]);
```

and HTML:

```
<wm-date-picker  
    ng-blur="onChange()" 
    data-ng-model="item.due">
</wm-date-picker>
```

Comment: Do I really need to create a watch?

Comment: @AndersLindén well, you need to listen on your model, I wrote this code before 2-3 years and maybe in latest 1.6.7 something changed. Anyways it can give you right direction.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without `$timeout`?

Comment: @AndersLindén generally `$timeout` puts event to end of queue before next digest cycle is triggered. I believe `scope.$apply();` should do the job but you can check it

Comment: I have found out that there is no error with my code, but I could not modify $scope.selectedDate from the directive because the datapicker was inside a ng-repeat.

Comment: @AndersLindén can you provide any demo that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: The issue would be that you cannot use ng-model="foo" inside a ng-repeat where foo is referring to $scope.foo. I solved it by using e.foo where e is the ng-repeat iterator.

Comment: @AndersLindén Sure, ng-model should be  bind to ng-repeat item

Comment: But if I do not prefix the ng-model expression with `e.`, then why cannot I refer to the scope?

Comment: @AndersLindén because each item of `ng-repeat` has his own scope. You can refer to scope with  `$root` a.e: '$root.myModel' inside `ng-repeat`

Comment: Thats really nice to know!